# How to validate multiple dropdownlist within a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Does anyone know how to validate multiple dropdown list within a repeater? Cannot seem to find any article of that on the net. I need a validation such that the first dropdown text is different from my second dropdown text and so on and so forth.

Comment: Looking for client-side validation ,jQuery ?

Comment: i dont mind. but prefer server side.

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for server side solution. Let's assume to validate on a button click, iterate through the repeater items, find dropdown and values in List.

```
List<string> ddlValues = new List<string>();

foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptItems.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropdownList ddl = (DropdownList)item.FindControl("YourDropdown");
        ddlValues.Add(ddl.SelectedValue);
    }
}


//Get duplicate values count
var duplicateKeys = list.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(group => group.Key);

if (duplicateKeys.Count>0) {} // duplicate values found . Do you stuff now
```

Comment: Hope this helps and gives you an idea